# Load specific content based on browser width using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am trying to load a Facebook embedded post with width 466 if browser width is greater than 500. If browser width is less than 500 a same Facebook post will be loaded but with width 350.
Here is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
<script>
if($(window).width()<500)
{

//Load the post below
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1" data-width="350"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner">Ted The Stoner</a>.</div></div>

}
else
{
//Load this post 
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1" data-width="466"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner">Ted The Stoner</a>.</div></div>
```

I am stuck about what to write instead of comments so that the script can load the correct version automatically.

EDIT   **My Updated code**

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
if($(window).width()>500)
{
$('.fb-post').attr('data-width',466);
}
});
</script>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1" data-width="350"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner">Ted The Stoner</a>.</div></div>
</div>
```

The page still loads he post at width 350. Here is the page http://8mags.com/bored/facebook/facebookpastpost01.php

**My page is responsive but the Fb- posts are not**

Comment: You cannot display HTML like that. This is not a server side language where you can print HTML stuff. Try changing data-width param of .fb-post with .attr('data-width'). Leave your div in HTML where it should be. You are changing data-width only, right?

Comment: Do you want to give your div "fb-post" the widths specified..??

Comment: Warp script around `$(document).ready({..})`

Comment: @trainoasis can I do it using php?  Benison Yes, I have to because they can't be made responsive( I read somewhere on stack overflow iteself). Gaurav How will that help to load content dynamically?

Comment: PHP is a server side language and is not meant to detect browser parameters. JS on the other hand is a client side language that can.

Comment: Alright, I will try it and get back.

Comment: Try putting the script after the `fb-post` element

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
    // You may or may not write the below code under the doc ready
    // Depends where and when you want the same to happen
    // For instance in the success function of any AJAX call or something like that
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fb-post').attr('data-width',350);
    });
</script>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1" data-width="466">
        <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1">
                Post
            </a>
            &nbsp;by&nbsp; 
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner">
                Ted The Stoner
            </a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Moreover if you want your page to work in responsive manner, you can control that using CSS. For that you can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). For more info, just google about "@media CSS"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't work that way. You can't print HTML just by leaving it inside if sentence. 
If you are changing only data-width parameter of your .fb-post element, then you can just leave your HTML in an .html file where it belongs and change your parameter using JS (jQuery) like this:

```
$('.fb-post').attr('data-width',350); // when your width is less then 500 for instance
```

Comment: Will it cut-off the post if someone resizes the window or just reload the fb post with width attribute 350

Comment: If you want to make it responsive then you should start off with a different approach perhaps. If someone reloads a page your script will be run again, which means your if-else stuff will do what it must again.

Comment: My page is responsive the embedded posts are not Facebook specifies a fixed width for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (script should be after the element you are looking for):

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1" data-width="350"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner/photos/a.255068134610728.57957.255065497944325/671495962967941/?type=1">Post</a> by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner">Ted The Stoner</a>.</div></div>
</div>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($(window).width()>500)
        {
            $('.fb-post').attr('data-width',466);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also add this to your script:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width()>500)
    {
        $('.fb-post').attr('data-width',466);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.fb-post').attr('data-width',350);
    }
});
```